# Divide two signal stream using GNU Radio but no result appear

Tags: echo, normalization, gnuradio, divide, pulse

Currently, I am developing a radar system using GNU Radio. At the end of the system, I would like to normalize the incoming echoe by read the value of the peak of the echoes, then I divide the incoming echoes with that value. I did it using "Divide" block.

[image: Radar Block System]

I was facing a problem that the gnu radio stop calculating and it was also verified on the BladeRF I was using that GNU radio is not calculating the magnitude of the echoes

[image: Radar Output]

Can anyone give me an idea why it happens like that?

Thank you!

Before I add the "divide" block, everything was working normally. The GNU Radio was able to calculate the echoes and I can also observe the output of the "Max N" block using QT GUI Number Sink.